# Angular Universal keeps loading forever if an error occurs

Tags: angular, angular-universal

I have an Angular Universal application running, which works fine, except for the fact that if an error occurs in the Angular code while rendering, instead of just spitting out a 500 response, it'll keep loading forever, until the server decides it's enough and spits out a 503.

An example of a failing page is https://msp-navigator.com/company/BpQzpAHaSFWbXvsgt3gc/saaslio. This one fails because it's only accessible to Admins, but in the resolve, due to a mistake, if you're not logged in, the user is undefined and the check fails. (`user.roles?.includes('Admin')` => `user?.roles?.includes('Admin')`. An example of a page that doesn't fail is https://msp-navigator.com/company/FsAqspiNe7jPCyOsIhT7/saaslio

The route in `server.ts` is defined like this:

```
  server.get('*', async (req, res, next) => {
    const origin = 'https://' + req.header('host');

    let settings: any;
    try {
      settings = await axios.get(environment.config.apiUrl + '/settings', {headers: {origin}});
    } catch (e) {
      res.sendStatus(404);

      return;
    }

    const transaction = Sentry.startTransaction({ op: 'main', name: 'Main' });
    Sentry.configureScope(scope => scope.setSpan(transaction));

    try {
      console.log('test 1');
      res.render(indexHtml, {
          req,
          providers: [
            { provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: req.baseUrl },
            { provide: SETTINGS, useValue: settings.data }
          ],
        });
    } catch (e) {
      console.log('test 2');
      res.send(500);
    }

    transaction.finish();
  });
```

In case of an error "test 1" is logged, then the error, but "test 2" is never logged.

I'm not sure what other code I can share, but please ask.

Any ideas on how I can resolve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because render is asynchronous, which means that errors will not be handled by your `try/catch`. But you can provide a callback to `render`

```
res.render(indexHtml, {
      req,
      providers: [
        { provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: req.baseUrl },
        { provide: SETTINGS, useValue: settings.data }
      ],
    }, (err: Error, html: string) =>
{

  if(!html)
  {
      res.status(500);
  }
  res.send(html || err.message);
});
```

Comment: i was so sure i tried that, but then it didn't work, and now it does. Thanks!